# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bachelor.ActionServlet

Tags: eclipse, servlets, classnotfoundexception

I know that this kind of question was asked a view times. But I read many posts about this and couldn't find the right answer to fix my problem.

I have this **web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Name</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ActionServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>bachelor.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ActionServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ActionServlet/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And of course there is the ActionServlet.java in the Folder: Java Resources/src/bachelor/ActionServlet.java

But when my index.jsp does this javascript:

```
$.get('ActionServlet',{user:username},function(responseText) { 
    $('#welcometext').text(responseText);         
});
```

I get the following error when runnig it in eclipse.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bachelor.ActionServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Does anyone know why I get this error? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you in Eclipse or deploying a war file?

Comment: I am in Eclipse, sorry that I forgot to mention that!

Comment: Apparently the project is not built. Can you ensure that the option *Project > Build Automatically* is checked?

Comment: @BalusC: Wooow that fixed it.. Thanks! Please write an answer, so that I can accept it. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hence BalusC doesn't write an answer. Here is his answer:

> Apparently the project is not built. Can you ensure that the option
>   Project > Build Automatically is checked?

Building the project fixed the problem.